# Odd behaviour on .reverse in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when I try to call .reverse on a Ruby string that contains apostrophes, it changes them to `\231\200?`. So on a string that is in the wrong order that contains `s’tI`calling reverse results in `It\231\200?s`, not `It's`. any ideas?

I am guessing this has to do with multi-byte safety? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine in ruby 1.9, which correctly deals with unicode:

```
>> "s’tI".reverse
=> "It’s"
```

In ruby 1.8 is broken, since it didn't have the same support for unicode strings and those apostrophes are non 1-byte ascii characters, they are multi-byte unicode characters (when encoded as UTF-8, for example).

Comment: Any way to deal with this in 1.8.7?

Comment: @d11wtq looks like it works, but only with unicode, which is likely the most common usecase. I recommend 1.9 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your string uses binary characters and not Unicode characters. You have to decode your binary string into Unicode string prior.

```
irb(main):001:0> "a\u9F9Cb".reverse
=> "b\u9F9Ca"
irb(main):002:0> "a\xE9\xBE\x9Cb".reverse
=> "a\x9C\xBE\xE9b"
irb(main):003:0> "a\xE9\xBE\x9Cb".force_encoding('UTF-8').reverse
=> "b\u9F9Ca"
```

Comment: This won't work in ruby 1.8, which I think is the more likely problem, given that ruby 1.9 defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: @d11wtq: Probably you're right, I haven't really programmed in Ruby (I'm not Ruby programmer), but there is chance that data from external source is in binary encoding still...

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained you're dealing with utf-8, so some characters are represented by more than one byte. There are also things like combining characters, surrogate pairs etc. ruby 1.8's byte by byte reversal ignores all of this so messes things up.

Ruby 1.9 does understand about string encodings, but if you're stuck on ruby 1.8, rails has its own system for dealing with utf8 - You can call `mb_chars` on a string and get back something that looks like a string, behaves like a string but implements methods like `reverse`,`downcase` in a unicode savvy way. For example you can do

```
reversed_string = string.mb_chars.reverse
```